# When update Linux Mint from 15 to 16?

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, upgrade

I would like to know if I have to, every time the new release of `Linux Mint` come out, upgrade my OS?

I had `Ubuntu` someday, and every half a year I burnt a CD and installed everything from the scratch (the whole OS and all my programs I need for work). It was kind of annoying but everytime I tried to do it with terminal, I always got some problems, so I burnt a CD ...

Anyway, now I have Mint 15. Should I upgrate to Mint 16? How long can I use Mint 15 to be able to get the newest available software and be secure?

Answer (score 2):

Linux Mint 15 (Olivia) is [supported until January 2014](http://www.linuxmint.com/oldreleases.php). So you would want to upgrade some time before then to ensure you continue to receive security updates.

If you do not want to upgrade regularly, you should look at the next LTS (long term support) release. The current one, 13 (Maya), is supported until April, 2017.

According to [Ubuntu's release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS), the next LTS will be released in April 2014, and will be supported until 2019. So you only have two upgrades between now and 2019 if you choose that path.